# How to get user tables from Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get table names for a particular user and then find the columns in that table.

Currently, I get all the user names with

```
select * from all_users;
```

once I have all the user names I would like to extract the tables these users have eventually find the columns in a particular table by a particular user.

> how do I find all the tables for a user?

So for example, if for user "James" I want all columns of his table "My_games"
I would use

```
DESCR James.My_games
```

however, I am not sure

> How to get columns info for multiple user tables so I could export it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

To find tables user contains:

```
SQL> select table_name from user_Tables;

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
EMP
DEPT
BONUS
```

To check which columns they contain:

```
SQL> select column_name from user_tab_Columns where table_name = 'DEPT';

COLUMN_NAME
------------------------------
DEPTNO
DNAME
LOC

SQL>
```

To select data from a table:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

To save contents into a file (from SQL*Plus): spool; the simplest (but not the best) way is

```
SQL> spool dept.txt
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> spool off
```

To export data into Excel - as you use SQL Developer:

- in Object navigator, right-click table you're intersted in
- select "Export"

  - check what you want, uncheck what you don't want
  - select format (Excel is already offered)
  - export data